# How can I determine if multiple .ZIP archives are encrypted/password protected?

Tags: zip

Preferably lists what is and is not encrypted/password protected as a .txt

I'm currently trying to figure out Unzip without much success. I just need to know if the .zip is password protected.

Comment: At least remember to mention your OS.

Comment: Various unzip commands include an option to test the archive. When you do this without providing a password any encrypted files in the zip file will produce errors as they can't be tested without it.

Comment: If you are a programmer at all, an option is a try/catch with Python's zipfile module (that's a quick and dirty way). Try opening it without a password, if you get an exception related to the password, append it to the file (i.e. create a list).

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty, but assuming your are working in Windows and have 7-zip installed. Create a batch file that contains the following:

```
@echo off

echo garbage | "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" t -y %1 >nul 2>nul

if errorlevel 2 (
   echo File is encrypted
   echo %1 >> encryptedlist.txt
   exit /b %errorlevel%
)

if errorlevel 0 (
   echo File is NOT encrypted
   echo %1 >> NOTencryptedlist.txt
   exit /b %errorlevel%
)
```

Then launch your batch file with the Zip file as the parameter, it will print the corresponding message via the return code. Also, it will put the Zip filename into one of two text files, "NOTencryptedlist.txt" or "encryptedlist.txt"

```
test.bat encypted.zip
```

OR

```
test.bat unencypted.zip
```

Comment: And if you have a whole bunch of .zip's to test you can run:

`FOR %1 in (*.ZIP) DO test.bat "%1"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Peazip](http://peazip.sourceforge.net). It will list all the encrypted files with a (*) mark after their names, and/or will also show (encrypted) text after the file name in the title bar if it is password protected.